# c++ undefined reference to PathFileExistsW (_imp__PathFileExistsW@4)

Tags: c++, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm trying to build headless blackcoin from source on Windows 8 with mingw 6.3
and I got the following error: `.../src/leveldb/libleveldb.a(env_win.o):env_win.cc:(.text+0xaff): undefined reference to '_imp__PathFileExistsW@4'`

This function is mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584(v=vs.85).aspx [image]

I would appreciate if someone can help me.
P.S. I linked the appropriate library.

Comment: Did you link the library mentioned?

Comment: Of course I linked the library.

Comment: wth bitcoin????

Answer (score 6):

Finally I was able to build it. Probably it is obvious for thoose guys who down voted the question. I simply answer since it might save time to somebody.

I relied on the Makefile which is a part of the project source code. Required library (shlwapi) present in the file so I was confused when it failed to build. Everything went well when I placed the library at the end of the linked files.

It was something like this

```
g++ ... -o -lshlwapi... /src/leveldb/libleveldb.a /src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
```

And became this

```
g++ ... -o /src/leveldb/libleveldb.a /src/leveldb/libmemenv.a -lshlwapi
```